# Can you change IntelliJ colors on per project basis?

Tags: intellij-idea

I often have 2-4 projects open at the same time in IntelliJ IDEA 15. It quickly becomes confusing switching between them, especially when classes are similarly named. Is there any way to use a different color scheme, or change a visual component of the IDE to easily identify which project is open?

**Update:**
As of IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2, the accepted answer is correct. When this was written I was using IntelliJ 15, and there was no way to accomplish this.

**Update:**
Due to JetBrains releasing a feature for this natively now (IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2), marking a new accepted answer. Setting a custom background is still very valid though!

Comment: WebStorm 2023.2 added support for coloured project headers. Expect this feature to also land in IntelliJ in 2023.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

7 years later, it's now available in [IntelliJ 2023.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/07/intellij-idea-2023-2/) (Released on July 26, 2023). No additional Plugins are needed anymore! In addition, with a project icon, it's very easy to recognize a workspace:

##### Colored Toolbar

[image: Screenshot colored IDEA]

##### Settings > Appearance > Use project colors in main toolbar

[image: Screenshot IDEA Settings]

It's now activated by default. In addition, you can add a project **icon**. To do so, simply put an icon named `icon.svg` and save it in the `.idea` folder in your project.

##### Change Color

The color can be changed in the right-click menu on the title bar.
[image: Screenshot change color]

Per default, the toolbar color is chosen by an index in the `.idea/workspace.xml`:

```xml
<component name="ProjectColorInfo">
   <![CDATA[{ 
             "customColor": "e55f25ff",
             "associatedIndex": 2 
            }]]>
</component>
```

The `associatedIndex` represents the order of your projects in the JetBrains Toolbox app. The `customColor` is the color in HEX format.

Comment: Unfortunately this is only available for the "New UI"

Comment: Thanks! Now my IntelliJ toolbar will have the same color as the project's identicon on GitLab. Convenient!

Answer (score 83):

You may want to set a different [background picture](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/setting-background-image.html) for each project to distinguish them from each other. This could also be a single solid color picture for example. Enter <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and search for the `Set Background Image` action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows).

Since 2023.2 it's possible to give your project [its own color](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/06/intellij-idea-2023-2-eap-6/#ColoredprojectheadersinthenewUI) in the window header and a custom SVG icon. You will have to have the new UI enabled for this feature.

Comment: Elegant, visible and very simple. It looks like this feature was introduced in 2016.2, but seeing as how it exactly answers the overall question I'll update the phrasing of the question.

Comment: Don't forget to check "This project only" (happened to me). To remove the background from a project again, use the "Clear and Close" button.

Comment: If you set a solid color picture of size 4000x23 to top center, no stretch, no repeat, it gives you a unobtrusive, highly visible colored line between menu and toolbar (if you use them)

Comment: Already 2019, but unfortunately the actual coloring still not exists. And this workaround is the best option available.

Comment: Does anybody know how to set the image path relative to the project?

Comment: Took me a while to figure out how @Johanness's method works in PhpStorm 2019, but it looks great. The image size for me was 4000 x 27. The alignment, position and stretch options are now graphical buttons.

Comment: This is perfect!! Especially you can set this only for one specific project. For me multiple projects now have each an own background image (with label of the project).
Additional i use specific colors for project file and for each project another. (File -> Settings -> appearance & behaviour -> File Colors -> + -> Project Files -> choose color

Answer (score 11):

I've had the exact same issue with JetBrains products, so I built a plugin that solves exactly that, it gives you the option to choose different colors for the title bar, which is seen in the task view mode, and thus helps you differentiate between open projects by color!

[image: Usage example]

You can download it by searching Project-Color in the JetBrains plugin marketplace window on your IDE, or from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nowtilous/Project-Color), where you can find more usage examples and a detailed explanation of the available features.

Comment: It doesn't work. Tried on mac ver. 2022.2.4

Comment: it needs some maintenance https://github.com/nowtilous/Project-Color/issues

Answer (score 9):

Another possible solution might be to create different scopes for your projects and apply custom colors.
Note: I see this more as a workaround because (IMHO) scopes should be mainly used 'in-project'. The downside with this solution is that you have also to handle the build-in scopes like *Test*.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My solution is based on the above - where I created a 1px x 1px coloured png and used it as the background image at.. 
Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance and there's a button 'Background image'
.. But .. 
I found that resizing my project window caused a huge lag in refreshing it to the new size.
.. So ..
I tried with a 200px x 200px image and resizing now works as normal.
Make sure you also tick the 'This project only' option.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set colors on project level.

See [IntelliJ Manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-and-ide-settings.html):

> The settings that pertain to a project, are marked with the icon current_project_icon in the Settings dialog.

Color setting does not show this icon (and text "For current project") next to the title.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted solution is correct but remember that if you have more than one project (with PHPStorm version) open while setting the background image both will get it even if you check "this project only". My solution has been to close one project apply the background to the other, close everything and then open the first project.

Comment: Good to note. You should also try to file a bug report with Jetbrains. That doesn't seem like intended behavior.