# Setting color for a specific project in IntelliJ

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea

Since I open a couple of IntelliJ projects at the same time, I'm looking for some setting that could help me quickly differentiate the projects at a glance, like customising the color of the bottom, left and/or right bars, or anything that could help.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you change IntelliJ colors on per project basis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733971/can-you-change-intellij-colors-on-per-project-basis)