# Changing Android Studio IDE color per project?

Tags: android, android-studio

currently I'm programming in more than two *Android Studio* projects at the same time, so when I try to switch between projects always select wrong one. I'm wondering if there is a way to **identify each IDE instance by a specific color**.

I've seen some posts but they point to *IntelliJ IDE*, for example:
[Can you change IntelliJ colors on per project basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733971/can-you-change-intellij-colors-on-per-project-basis/40861163#40861163)

Also, I've checked out *Material UI* plugin but premium version has that feature (I don't wanna pay for just one feature).

**Additional note:** I'm using latest IDE version (Hedgehog 2023.1.1), I was using Giraffe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just I wanna update this question with an answer that I've found recently.

New Android Studio IDE version **Iguana 2023.2.1** has now an option to enable different color for each project opened. The option is *Use project colors in main toolbar*.

[image: Settings]

And the result looks like:

[image: Color for project]